# How can i add total label to mat paginator range - angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Is it possible to add a label after 1-5 of 20  in angular material table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely implement it using **MatPaginatorIntl**. First create a class which extends **MatPaginatorIntl** and override the getRangeLabel method of this.

Mat paginator api - https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api (you will find the guidance here)

Please use this stackblitz for your reference, look at MyCustomPaginatorIntl in app.component.ts - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-jthuj9

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jasdeep Singh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60613143/12106768):

If you just want to add the word "total" at the end of the label, you don't need to rewrite the default behavior of `getRangeLabel`, you can call the implementation of the base class in your override and modify its output like this:

```js
export class MyCustomPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // copy super.getRangeLabel reference before overriding it
    const superGetRangeLabel = this.getRangeLabel;
    this.getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
      return `${superGetRangeLabel(page, pageSize, length)} total`;
    };
  }
}
```

This also works if you want to change the language of the label by replacing the word "of" for something else like `.replace(/of/g, 'de')`, although I would add unit tests for this so that you know if the lib changes the default label when you upgrade it.